# Prevent logout if conditions aren't fulfilled

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I created `status.jsp` for inserting status data of a file in database. There are two option for status(IN or OUT).On submitting it goes to `inserted.jsp` which says data inserted and gives a goback link to `status.jsp` for inserting more or logout.
I want the user to not be able to logout unless he has choosen option IN(afte doing out).
For example user entered status out for some file number after submitting it leads to `inserted.jsp` page from where he goes back to `status.jsp` page and tries to logout but he/she is not able to before he entered status IN for the same file number which he entered out.How should i do this?
If someone could give a link for some similar example or a site where something similar is explained will also be helpful

status.jsp(only body)

```
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue;">
    <%
        String userName = null;
        String sessionID = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals("user")) {
                    userName = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    %>
    <header>
        <h3>File Tracking System</h3>
        <div><span style="float:right">Hi <%=userName%></span></div> 
        <br>
    </header>
    <a href="create1.jsp"><font color="black">back</font></a>
    <form action=" LogoutServlet" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
    </form>
    <nav>
        <h3>Change Status</h3>
        <form action="statusServlet" method="post">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            File Number :<select name="files">
                                <%
                                    try {
                                        String sql = "select * from files";
                                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login",
                                                "root", "root");
                                        Statement st = con.createStatement();
                                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                                        while (rs.next()) {
                                %>                          
                                <option value="<%=rs.getString("fileno")%>"><%=rs.getString("fileno")%></option>
                                <%}
                                        rs.close();
                                        st.close();
                                        con.close();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                %> 
                            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>  
                            File Department :<select name="departments">
                                <%
                                    try {
                                        String sql = "select * from department";
                                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login",
                                                "root", "root");
                                        Statement st = con.createStatement();
                                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                                        while (rs.next()) {
                                %>                          
                                <option value="<%=rs.getString("departmentname")%>"><%=rs.getString("departmentname")%></option>
                                <%}
                                        rs.close();
                                        st.close();
                                        con.close();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                %>
                            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                            File Status:  
                            <br>
                            <select name="input">
                                <option>IN</option>
                                <option>OUT</option>
                            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </nav>
    <section><img src="css/NSIC-logo1.png" width="537" height="267" alt="NSIC-logo1"/>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Copyright 2016 NSIC. All right reserved.                             
    </footer>
</body>
```

statusServlet.java(only inserting value in database)

```
public class statusServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")) {
                System.out.println("JSESSIONID=" + cookie.getValue());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    System.out.println("User=" + session.getAttribute("user"));
    if (session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
        String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            String fname = request.getParameter("files");
            String departments = request.getParameter("departments");
            String input = request.getParameter("input");
            int i;
            if (input.equals("IN")) {
                i = 1;
            } else {
                i = 0;
            }

            Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();

            String sql = "insert into status(fname,fstatus,department) values (?,?,?) ";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            pstmt.setString(1, fname);
            pstmt.setInt(2, i);
            pstmt.setString(3, departments);

            int rs = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            if (rs > 0) {
                if (input.equals("IN")) {
                    String sql1 = "update files set location='" + departments + "' where fileno='" + fname + "'";
                    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
                    int rs1 = st.executeUpdate();
                }
                status = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (status) {
            response.sendRedirect("inserted.jsp");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("Values have been inserted," + user);
            //out.flush();
        } else {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("failed");
            response.sendRedirect("notinserted.jsp");
        }

    } else {
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }
  }
}
```

inserted.jsp(only body)

```
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue;">
    <header>Data inserted!!</header>
    <a href="fileStatus.jsp"><font color="black"> goback</font></a>
    <form action=" LogoutServlet" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
    </form>
    <footer>
        Copyright 2008 NSIC. All right reserved.                             
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using HttpSession to remember previous selection**

```
// add following lines in 'doPost' method after session initialization in statusServlet 
String input = request.getParameter("input");   // you have wrote this one already

if(input != null && (input.equals("IN") || input.equals("OUT"))){
    session.setAttribute("last-value", input);
}
```

and...

```
//wrap logout form in status.jsp like following:

<%
    String lastValue = session.getAttribute("last-value");
    if(lastValue != null && lastValue.equals("IN")){
%>
        <form action=" LogoutServlet" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
        </form>
<%
    }
%>
```

**Note**: I haven't tested this, I just wrote the code in Notepad++

Please comment if you need more help